# Iphone UI Automation

Tags: iphone, ios-ui-automation

HI, Using the new UIAutomation API one can automate UI in an app, my question is can it be done for an inbuilt app as well or to be more precise can one finish/end the voicecall or send an sms using the UIAutomation API

Answer (score 2):

Additionally I would check Intsruments documentation, as in one of documents apple says:

> Note:  For your protection, the
>   instrument does not allow you to
>   process any application that is not
>   code-signed with your provisioning
>   profile. This includes any copy that
>   has been downloaded from the iTunes App
>   Store.

Answer (score 1):

The UI automation APIs are intended for automated testing, not automatic functionality in a shipping app.

To answer your question, no, you cannot control the UI of other apps such as SMS or Phone using the automation APIs.

If you submit an app to the App Store that contains these APIs I'm pretty sure your app will be rejected very quickly.